# How can I solve SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Tags: python, multithreading, syntax-error

I am trying to run this code here:

```
threads = [threading.Thread(name='ThreadNumber{}'.format(n),target=SB, args(shoe_type,model,variant)) for size in SizeList for n in range(ThreadCount)]
```

However this is what my terminal is returning:

```
   threads = [threading.Thread(name='ThreadNumber{}'.format(n),target=SB, args(s
hoe_type,model,variant)) for size in SizeList for n in range(ThreadCount)]
                                                                           ^

SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Is there anyway I can fix this?

SB is referring to a function that I am trying to run.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  The error message seems quite clear: you put a keyword argument `name=` first, a positional argument `args` second.  This is illegal syntax.

Comment: You are giving a keyword argument `name` and `target` and then giving the third argument `args(shoe_type,model,variant)` without any key which is throwing the error.

Comment: I am stuck on how to solve this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the order in which we pass (and receive) arguments to a function matters.

*Positional* arguments come first, *variable-length* arguments come next, *variable-length keyword arguments* come last.

The expected syntax looks like this:

```
function(arg, *args, **kwargs)
```

The argument names above are only conventional examples, so a real-world function will look like:

```
about_user(name, *hobbies, **favorite_foods)
```

If we call (or receive) with the argument types out of order, we get errors similar to the one you encountered. In your specific case, your keyword arguments are first, when they should be last.

I wrote a [small article about `*args` and `**kwargs`](https://dev.to/adamlombard/python-what-are-args-and-kwargs-35co) that has a few more related details and examples.